# Jenkins - add JDK and add Maven button disappears when I click them

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, plugins, path

I face an issue while adding path for JDK and Maven in Jenkins under Jenkins => Global Tools config. When I click the button **add JDK** or **add Maven** to add the path, the button disappear. Can you suggest why this is happening and how this can be fixed ?

I installed JDK version 1.8 and Maven 3.8.3 on the same server where Jenkins is running.

**Jenkins version: 2.320**

Answer (score 0):

It was corrected from last jenkins release.